# Mutt email client not receiving or sending mail

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I am trying to setup the mutt email client on my Linux system, however, I am running into some issues.

To begin with, when Mutt launches it states the following at the bottom of the screen: `gnutls_handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received`. When I go to send an email (to myself for testing purposes) and input my login information mutt states that it's logging in but the `Logging in...` message only stays on the screen for a split second and afterwards nothing happens (no email is sent).

Here is my .muttrc file:

```
## IMAP CREDENTIALS
set smtp_url = "smtp://jacksewell@smtp.kolabnow.ch:587/"
#set smtp_pass = "password"
set from = "jacksewell@kolabnow.ch"
set realname = "Jack Sewell"

## IMAP SETTINGS
# activate TLS if available on the server
set ssl_starttls=yes
# always use SSL when connecting to a server
set ssl_force_tls=yes
# Don't wait to enter mailbox manually 
unset imap_passive        
# Automatically poll subscribed mailboxes for new mail (new in 1.5.11)
set imap_check_subscribed

set folder = "imaps://imap.kolabnow.ch:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"

## GENERIC
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates
# Move read messages from your spool mailbox to your $mbox mailbox
set move = no
# Reduce polling frequency to a sane level
set mail_check=60
# And poll the current mailbox more often (not needed with IDLE in post 1.5.11)
set timeout=10
# keep a cache of headers for faster loading (1.5.9+?)
set header_cache=~/.hcache
# Display download progress every 5K
set net_inc=5
# Don't switch to next mail when paging down in a mail and hitting bottom
set pager_stop=yes
# Confirm quit

set quit=ask-yes
# Date format in index view. Standard strftime syntax.
set date_format="!%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M:%S%p %Z"
# Default index format
#set index_format="%4C %Z %{%b %d} %-15.15L (%?l?%4l&%4c?) %s"
set index_format="%4C %Z %{%b %d %H:%M}  %-15.15L (%?l?%4l&%4c?) %s"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem maybe your use of two @ characters in the values of "spoolfile" and/or "smtp_url". I am pretty sure that won't work.

I don't set "spoolfile" myself, but rather the shell variable MAILDIR e.g. I use:

```
imaps://imapusername@imapservername.domain.tld
```

In my muttrc I set "folder" to a similar value:

```
set folder = imaps://imapusername@imapservername.domain.tld/INBOX
# folder means the default location of your mailboxes
#  Used as the basis for the '+' and "=" shortcuts
...
```

Rightly or wrongly, I notice that I am also setting these imap related variables:

```
set ssl_force_tls = yes
set ssl_verify_host = no
set imap_authenticators = "digest-md5:cram-md5"
```

For sending email, via SMTP, my mutt uses a locally installed Postfix instance. So in this case I don't have the corresponding configuration to yours. But here I am also dubious about the use of two @ characters ...

Have you already successfully used other IMAP clients from the same system/network? If not you should also verify basic connectivity to the desired IMAP/SMTP server(s). This can be done via the openssl command for example.

Good luck!

Comment: What would the imap username be? I'm guessing the part before the "@" in my email address?

Comment: I am greeted with a ` SSL failed: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol  ` error with the updated muttrc in the OP @Robb W.

Comment: I have updated the OP with my new muttrc. With this muttrc it says "Login failed" once I input my username and password. However, it does have me accept a certificate.

Comment: Well, that's both good and bad. Good in that it appears you are now connecting successfully, but bad that you (still) cannot login. The error "Login failed" suggests to me that either the username or password you are using is incorrect. You should verify with the service provider that you have both of these correct. The IMAP username is typically, but not necessarily, the first part of the email address as you suggest.

Comment: If the access info. is verified as being correct, then the next logical step would be to have the server sysadmin team check the logs on their side to determine the specific error or failure that is occurring. Hard to know what else to suggest after that.